# python matplotlib increase bar label font size

Tags: python, matplotlib, label, bar-chart, font-size

I have a subplot which may include different stacked bar charts. I want to increase the font size of the bar label as it is appearing small.
for ex. in

```
ax.bar(adjlocs, ...
 label='...', ...)
```

I want the font size of what is set to label to be larger. I did find ways to increase the text size of others in the plot except this one. How to achieve this? Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, I got the answer.
You can change the fontsize using ax.legend:

```
ax.legend(loc='best', fontsize=25)
```

Hope it helps anybody else with the same problem!

Comment: A full working example would be helpful.

Comment: @littleO feel free to improve the answer with an edit.

Answer (score 6):

If I understood your question correctly, you are trying to change the font size not the axis or legend, but on the actual values that are written on the bars. The easiest way is to add this:

```
plt.rcParams['font.size'] = 6
```

I think the default is 12.